# conflicts phonegap and jQuery/jQuery Mobile...?

Tags: jquery, cordova, conflict

I come for ask if you know some conflicts of jQuery/jQuery Mobile with phonegap, because I've an app made with jQuery Mobile and phonegap, and when I include the cordova.js the app doesn't work, that is, I see the UI well, but the app doesn't make anything...and some divs should change but they keep stopped.
Regards, Daniel

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>APP THE SUPERDRIVER</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- necesario para jQuery Mobile -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" /> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css" /> <!-- incluimos la hoja de estilos -->
        <!-- incluimos el api de PhoneGap -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="api.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page"> <!-- jQuery Mobile: div que hará el papel de página de nuestra app -->
        <div data-role="content"> <!-- jQuery Mobile: div que hará el papel de contenedor -->
            <div id="div"> <!-- div que contiene la esfera central, la que marca la marcha recomendada -->
                <div class="contenido">1</div>
            </div>
            <div id="divSupIzq"> <!-- div que contiene la esfera superior izquierda , que marca la velocidad actual -->
                <div class="contenidos"><div id="textoDinamico">120 </div><div id="textoEstatico">KM/H</div></div>
            </div>
            <div id="divSupDer"> <!-- div que contiene la esfera superior derecha , que marca los avisos -->
                <div class="contenidos">zona de</br>avisos</div>
            </div>
            <div id="divInfIzq"> <!-- div que contiene la esfera inferior izquierda , que contiene información -->
                <div class="contenidos">zona de</br>informaci&oacute;n</div>
            </div>
            <div id="divInfDer"> <!-- div que contiene la esfera inferior derecha , que marca las alarmas -->
                <div class="contenidos"><img src="aceleracionBrusca.gif" class="aceleracionBrusca" style="display:none"/>
                <p>zona de</br>alarmas</p></div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div data-role="navbar" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b"> <!-- jQuery Mobile: div que hará el papel de menú footer -->
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twoo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>  
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I comment/remove the quinth line, the app works. But I need include phonegap api. 
NOTE: In my javascript files, I use:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var watchIDgeolocation = null;      // ID que devolverá el objeto geolocation

function onDeviceReady() {
var options = { frequency: 1000 };  // Cada 1 s queremos obtener los datos
watchIDgeolocation = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccessGeolocation, onErrorGeolocation, options);
}

var onSuccessGeolocation = function(position){
   // here I call other functions and make things through jQuery 
}

function onErrorGeolocation(error) {
 alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

But this javascript code don't work if I include phonegap library...only without it...I think that it works without this phonegap api, because is code part of the api of html5, right?
Best regards

Comment: can you put the source which we can check, otherwise the provided information is not sufficient to come to any conclusion

Comment: Hi! Don't sure if this solved the issue really...but after do this, my app works including jQuery and PhoneGap. I was including cordova 1.7.0, so I've included the last version (1.9) and now it works.